# hand detection in c using opencv capturing video from kinect device

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, kinect

I am working on a project in which I have to detect the hand in a video. Kinect is being used to capture the video. I have already tried skin segmentation using hsv colour scheme. It works well when I get the video from cam of my laptop but does not work with Kinect. I have also tried colour segmentation and thresholding but it is also not working well. I am using opencv in c. I will be grateful if someone can give any type of suggestions or steps to detect the hand.

Comment: Do you want to detect the hand using your own algorithms? The Kinect comes with libraries which allow you to detect the hand in real-time robustly

Comment: Please tell me about that library for hand detection. Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific about what "does not work" or is "not working well".  Is the image quality bad?  Are the colors different?  The Kinect also has depth data, so you may want to take advantage of that, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenNI to obtain a skeleton of the person which robustly tracks the hand in your video. E.g. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZfJn-h5h2k